# How to sort rows in a specific Section of uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, row, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am populating my `tableView` with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I am using an `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the sections and rows. Actually, I am sorting from new to old.
But now, I want only to sort the rows from Section X alphabetically(for example section with name:"own sets" sort rows from A-Z).

Example:

```
Section A
  row Za
  row Ya
  row Xa  
Section B  
  row Wb
  row Vb
  row Ub  
Section C      <--- want to sort the rows in this section from A-Z  
  row Fc
  row Ec
  row Dc
```

Is it possible to sort differently in sections while using `NSFetchedResultsController`?

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried using NSSortDescriptor

Comment: I have used two sortdescriptors and that worked. thank you.